# How to dismiss Custom Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog, android-alertdialog

i have a Custom Alert Dialog , i have a imageView For close Dialog but i don`t know how to do it. 
I try to do it by dismiss or cancel, but it does not work

```
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            final View viewLayout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_addstudent_items , null);

            dialog.setView(viewLayout);
            ImageView closeIcon_img = (ImageView)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_img_close);

            closeIcon_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             // I want To dismiss Here

            });

            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like this create `AlertDialog` form `AlertDialog.Builder`.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    final View viewLayout = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_addstudent_items , null);
    dialog.setView(viewLayout);
    ImageView closeIcon_img = (ImageView)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_img_close);
    final AlertDialog  alertDialog=dialog.create();
    closeIcon_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: i dont have this option @ADM

Comment: What option ? See clearly i have crated a `AlertDialog` from `Builder`. Which you did not .

Comment: sorry i didn't carefully check your answer . my problem was resolved . just , can you explain to me Why do we have to do this? @ADM

Comment: With `Builder` we rely on `DialogInterface` to access `AlertDialog` methods . `DialogInterface` can be access while adding native positve and negative buttons. With custom view we need to create the `Dialog`.